# What is triggering this PHP parse error with getdate() on PHP 5.3.6?

Tags: php, timezone, getdate

I am getting the getdate(); PHP parse error below on every page of my Etomite install.

Since I tried setting my server timezone to EST/EDT but the error persists. I also searched the Etomite forum and StackOverflow but could not find a solution.

Note: The server has recently been updated to PHP 5.3.6

Here's the error, any help would be greatly appreciated!

---

```
Etomite encountered the following error while attempting to parse the requested resource:
« PHP Parse Error »

PHP error debug
Error:  getdate(): It is not safe to rely on the system's timezone settings. You are *required* to use the date.timezone setting or the date_default_timezone_set() function. In case you used any of those methods and you are still getting this warning, you most likely misspelled the timezone identifier. We selected 'America/Los_Angeles' for 'PDT/-7.0/DST' instead 
Error type/ Nr.:    Warning - 2 
File:   /var/www/vhosts/xxxxxxxxxxxxx.ca/httpdocs/manager/includes/visitor_logging.inc.php 
Line:   81 
Line 81 source: $accesstime = getdate(); 

Parser timing
MySQL:  0.0000 s s  (0 Requests)
PHP:    0.0086 s s 
Total:  0.0086 s s
```

---

Comment: It's not a parse error, it's an error in determining your timezone. What have you set exactly as your timezone and where?

Comment: well it is already explaining in the debug, isn't it? "It is not safe to rely on the system's timezone settings. You are *required* to use the date.timezone setting or the date_default_timezone_set() function. In case you used any of those methods and you are still getting this warning, you most likely misspelled the timezone identifier."

Comment: I think you should choose different formatting for the timezone.  see this: http://www.zen-cart.com/forum/showthread.php?t=150719

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PHP will report an `E_STRICT` error when the timezone isn't specified.  In your case, the offending call occurs on line 81 of `visitor_logging.inc.php.`

Somewhere before that file is included, you can set the timezone with the following call:

```
// Use your own correct time zone
date_default_timezone_set('America/Los_Angeles');
```

Comment: This fixed it. I really appreciate your time and response... You rock!